# Entity Framework cannot connect to MySQL from Python subprocess

Tags: python, entity-framework-core, subprocess, .net-6.0

I have a console app written in .NET 6. It connects to MySQL database and performs some queries. It works perfectly fine when called from IDE or terminal.

I am writing a script in Python 3 that will call this console app like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([path_to_exe, json_file, "-o", out_dir], env={'ConnectionStrings__WriteConnection':'server=localhost; port=3306; database=test; user=root; password=; Persist Security Info=False; Connect Timeout=300'})
```

It will start .NET app but the app will fail with `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

I validated that connection string is passed correctly to the .NET app and, as I wrote above, it works in all other cases except when the app is executed with Popen.

Any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what is causing this strange behavior.

If you pass **env** to **subprocess.Popen** you will not pass environment variables of the system. I was aware of that, but I figured I didn't need them.

The problem was that **SYSTEMROOT="C:\WINDOWS"** environment variable was missing and for some strange reason Entity Framework could not connect to MySQL without it. If I pass that in **env** then everything works correctly.

Not sure why is this happening, but it solved my issue. So to be on the safe side, you can use

```
import os  
proc = subprocess.Popen([path_to_exe, json_file, "-o", out_dir], env={**os.environ, 'ConnectionStrings__WriteConnection':'server=localhost; port=3306; database=test; user=root; password=; Persist Security Info=False; Connect Timeout=300'})
```

and it will load all system environment variables.